# CMake LINK_PRIVATE and its "inheritance"

Tags: c++, cmake, static-linking

If I have a my_library.lib file which links against several other .lib files like:

```
add_library( my_library ...)
target_link_libraries( my_library LINK_PUBLIC lib1 lib2 ...)
```

if I now link this my_library.lib file into another library (which also needs lib1, lib2, etc.. that's the reason of the LINK_PUBLIC in the code above) with **LINK_PRIVATE**

```
target_link_libraries( some_other_library LINK_PRIVATE my_library )
```

will I "protect" the lib1, lib2 and other libraries I **only used to compile my_library**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LINK_PUBLIC`: makes transitive dependencies of the currently linked target visible to other targets which are going to be linked against the current one. So `lib1` and `lib2` will be linked along with `my_library` when `my_library` is linked against something else.

`LINK_PRIVATE`: makes transitive dependencies of the currently linked target invisible to other targets which are going to be linked against the current one. So `lib1` and `lib2` will not be linked along with `my_library` when `my_library` is linked against something else.

To conclude, when `some_other_library` will be linked against something else, its dependencies will not be seen to those targets it is linked against because of the final `LINK_PRIVATE`.